# Cross-sectional dependence and second generation unit root tests

Tags: panel-data, stationarity, cross-correlation, unit-root

Could someone explain me in simpler terms what a cross sectional dependence and panel unit root tests does in practice? How is panel unit root tests different from any other unit root tests such as ADF for instance? What if I get a result that indicates cross sectional dependence (Pesaran CD) but is stationary according to the Breitung Variance Ratio Test?

To provide some context: I am running a quantile regression with day ahead price as dependent variable with different explanatory variables. Due to all of the 24 prices being set the day before, the data should be treated as panel data rather than a time series (subsetting for each hour). Therefore, I want to explore the characteristics of these panels.

I am using the packages `plm` and `egcm` in R.